# HTML form input using image rating

Tags: html, image, forms, input, submit

I'm trying to create a html form for inputting risk of activities that includes TWO images for inputting data: a) severity of the risk and b) likelihood of the risk happening. I have tried using imagemaps without success:

```
<form method="post">
    <map name="image_map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,25" alt="1" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="10,0,20,25" alt="2" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="20,0,30,25" alt="3" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="30,0,40,25" alt="4" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="40,0,50,25" alt="5" />
    </map>
    <input name="severity" type="image" width="50" height="25" src="images/rating.png" usemap="#image_map" /> 
    <input name="liklihood" type="image" width="50" height="25" src="images/rating.png" usemap="#image_map" />
    <input type="image" src="images/document_add.png" name="add" width="32" height="32">
</form>
```

but when I click on an image, it submits the form (note there are THREE images, one is used to submit the form). 
I also thought about splitting up the images and using them as radio buttons, but it seems that I would have to use the same image for each radio button, i.e. values for 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 would all be the same image.

The image looks like this: [image: rating image]. The user should be able to click on part of it and return between 1 and 5 for each of the two input fields.

How can I do this with two images in the form?

Comment: Use this tool, helps alot! 
Tool: http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: Thanks for that, however this does not help with my problem. I am unsure whether using an imagemap is the correct way to go about this.